# c# check elements in xml

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

How do I check an xml file to determine if some elements exist?  For example I have the XML  from:

`http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=vilnius&hl=eng`

I want check if the word "wind_condition" exists:

`if ("wind_condition") {do something}`

Comment: I had to edit to try to figure out what was being asked.  Hope I got it.

Comment: read up on reading child nodes in xml.  http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?292473-Reading-Child-nodes-from-XML-file-C

Comment: Are you looking for the string `wind_condition` in there, or an element called `wind_condition`? The question doesn't make this clear.

Comment: looking for elements `wind_condition`

Comment: Where can the `wind_condition` be?  Just in the current_conditions or in other blocks as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will determine if the file contains the word `wind_condition`.

```
if(xml.ToString().Contains("wind_condition"))
{
    // do something
}
```

In case you want the element `wind_condition`

```
if(xml.Descendants("wind_condition").Count() > 0)
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: OP is looking for an element, not a string.

Comment: Per the question (`How do I check an xml file to determine if some elements exist?`) and the comments (`looking for elements wind_condition`), he wants an element.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

XmlNodeList list = xml.SelectNodes("//wind_condition");

Then, just check the list returned and process accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this to query the document, using Linq-to-Xml (untested):

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=vilnius&hl=eng");
XElement[] myElements = xdoc.Root.Element("weather")
    .Elements()
    .Where(xelement => xelement.Element("wind_condition") != null)
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: The example XML has the `wind_condition` in `current_conditions` rather than `forecast_information`.

Comment: @zimdanen good catch.  Updated my answer to select all children of *weather* using **Elements()**.

Answer (score 2):

Since your root node is xml_api_reply, following should return you a bool whether wind_condition exist or not (I just tested it and it seems to be working)

```
var result = (from t in loadedData.Descendants("xml_api_reply")
                     select t.Descendants("wind_condition").Any()).Single();

if(result) // equals to if wind_condition exists
{
}
```